# Is it possible to change the default launch behavior of apps, either individually or generally?

Tags: applications

I don't like that apps naturally pull focus when you launch them, especially when they launch in multiple stages (like many games/ide's). I saw another post that showed how use terminal to launch apps into the background or hidden, and I'm hoping to find a way to make this the default behavior.

An example to clarify: Say I have my Mail app open full screen and I'm looking through my emails, and one or a few have links that I want to open, but not necessarily go to right away. I'd like to be able to launch Safari and open the link with out getting pulled away from looking through my email.

I'm running Mojave 10.14.6 on a MacBook Pro. Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: I've never tried it pre-launch as I never quit Safari, but right-click/open link behind Mail does it for me.

Comment: Ooh, thank you, that does help with that specific example. I'd still like to generalize the behavior though, and make it the default.